# How to have a rigidbody object "ride" a falling platform, while still being able to move horizontally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I'm making a 2D game in Unity, which has falling platforms that the player can "ride" down. I want the player to still be able to move left or right (ie horizontally) while standing on a falling platform. Without additional code, just using the Rigidbody physics, the player does fall along with the platform, but the falling is choppy, and the game doesn't always see the player is standing on the platform (important because the player can only jump while standing on something).

I've tried setting the player object's `transform.translate`, which prevents the player from moving left or right as long as it is touching the platform. I've also tried setting the player object's `transform.parent` to the platform's `transform`, but that "glues" the player in place to the platform, preventing even jumping. I've also tried searching for a solution/example, and there are plenty of examples for riding a left-right moving platform, but I haven't been able to get those examples to work for a falling platform.

Here is the script controlling the players left-right movement and jumping. This is attached to the player object:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float jumpForce = 5;
  public float horizontalSpeed = 0.1F;
  public LayerMask whatIsGround;

  private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
  private Collider2D myCollider;
  private bool grounded;
  private float lastHorizontalInput;

  void Start()
  {
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
  }

  void Update()
  {
    // If the player is trying to jump, only do so if the player is on a platform
    grounded = Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers(myCollider, whatIsGround);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && grounded)
    {
      rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }

    MoveHorizonltally();
  }

  private void MoveHorizonltally()
  {
    float horizontalVelocity;
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    horizontalVelocity = GetHorizontalVelocity(horizontalInput);
    if (horizontalVelocity != 0)
    {
      rb2d.position = new Vector2(rb2d.position.x + horizontalVelocity, rb2d.position.y);
    }
  }

  private float GetHorizontalVelocity(float horizontalInput)
  {
    // Default to no horizontal motion
    float result = 0;
    bool leftPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
    bool rightPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);

    // Only a left key is being pressed; the player is going left
    if (leftPressed && !rightPressed)
    {
      result = -1 * horizontalSpeed;
    }
    // Only a right key is being pressed; the player is going right
    else if (rightPressed && !leftPressed)
    {
      result = horizontalSpeed;
    }
    // Both keys are being pressed
    else if (leftPressed && rightPressed)
    {
      // The most recent key press gets priority; ignore the oldest key press
      if (lastHorizontalInput < 0)
      {
        // Oldest key pressed is a left direction, so go right
        result = horizontalSpeed;
      }
      else
      {
        // Oldest key pressed is a right direction, so go left
        result = -1 * horizontalSpeed;
      }
    }

    lastHorizontalInput = horizontalInput;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Here is the script responsible for making the platform fall. This is attached to the platform object:

```
public class PlatformFalling : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float fallSpeed;
  private GameObject player;

  public void Start()
  {
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    bool playerIsOnPlatform = player.GetComponent<Collider2D>().IsTouching(GetComponent<Collider2D>()); ;
    Vector2 fallDistance = Vector2.down * fallSpeed;

    transform.Translate(fallDistance);
    if (playerIsOnPlatform)
    {
      player.transform.Translate(fallDistance);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all whenever using physics don't apply any movement via the `Transform` component as this breaks physics and collision detection. And then simply make sure that gravity affects the player more than the platform

Comment: @derHugo This worked! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it and give you credit?